# Is there any health-related site like Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any health-related site like Stack Overflow?

Comment: Related: [Will a Q&A site about medical be provided?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/will-a-qa-site-about-medical-be-provided), [Health side effects due to cycling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161806/health-side-effects-due-to-cycling) and [Question asking for medical advice — is this a liability problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64559/question-asking-for-medical-advice-is-this-a-liability-problem)

Comment: Er, ignore my vote to close this question. I went the wrong direction (the other one should be closed as a dupe of this).

Comment: ...and it is reopened by Popular Demand!

Comment: [Here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health)'s a new proposal for a Health site about medical issues.

Comment: [Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com/) is now in public beta

Answer (score 6):

There is this [beta site](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) on physical fitness.

Comment: But please read the [Physical Fitness FAQ](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) first. We don't take all "health" topics.

Answer (score 2):

If you want there to be one, it seems like a decent idea to float/support on Area 51.

Comment: FYI it was attempted in 2010 but it failed. How much has changed since then? I don't know.

Comment: @Pops There was another one re-opened recently, but it is still slow-going: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health