# Question asking for medical advice -- is this a liability problem?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

This question on the Bicycles beta seems to be a bit of red flag, liability-wise:

[What do you do to heal yourself more quickly after a crash?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/967/what-do-you-do-to-heal-yourself-more-quickly-after-a-crash)

I started a thread about my concerns in the meta.bicycles site: [On or off topic: Medical advice](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/on-or-off-topic-medical-advice)

Has this ever come up before on other sites?

Comment: That's some photo.

Comment: Came up on [Food](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/266/are-food-safety-questions-a-liability) as well. But seriously, drink used marinades. They're tasty.

Comment: I know one site where this will *not* be a problem: The [Apocalyptic Defense](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2868/apocalyptic-defense) site when it gets resurrected one day. Medical advice will be fair game there, as it always relates to a situation where there is no more civilization, hence, no lawyers who could sue you for bad advice.

Comment: Related: [Is there any health-related site like Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33862/is-there-any-health-related-site-like-stack-overflow), [Will a Q&A site about medical be provided?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/will-a-qa-site-about-medical-be-provided) and [Health side effects due to cycling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161806/health-side-effects-due-to-cycling)

Comment: Related: [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) for a health stack exchange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Stack Overflow the community have generally gotten behind "Ask a doctor, not the internet" type answers and comments.

On sites relating to more physical activities the culture may be a little different, but you could start by trying "See an expert" type advice and seeing if the community goes with it.

Comment: I think there are sites where disallowing *anything* medical would really take away a big chunk from the site's question base - e.g. cycling.

Comment: @Pekka: In which case I imagine the community won't go for it. Any martial arts related site will be like that too. On a camping/hiking type site you would *expect* first aid to be a topic of some interest. This is going to have to be thrashed out where and as it comes up, but I think that suggesting a professional opinion is fair more-or-less every time.

Comment: absolutely. I imagine most pieces of advice would contain a "You should ask a doctor about this, but..." part, which is fine

Answer (score 8):

> **Limitation of liability**
>
> In no event shall Stack Overflow, its directors, officers, shareholders, employees or members be liable with respect to the Network or the Services for (a) any indirect, incidental, punitive, or consequential damages of any kind whatsoever; (b) damages for loss of use, profits, data, images, Subscriber Content or other intangibles; (c) damages for unauthorized use, non-performance of the Network, errors or omissions; or (d) damages related to downloading or posting Content. Stack Overflow's and the Network's collective liability under this agreement shall be limited to three hundred United States Dollars. Some states do not allow the exclusion or limitation of incidental or consequential damages, so the above limitations and exclusions may not apply to Subscriber.

Part *(a)* seems to be applicable in this situation.

Section 9 of the [Terms of Service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service).

Comment: That's good to know, but is it still a good idea to allow this sort of question? Do we want to stomp a question like this? (Crashing a bicycle *is* a pretty common situation.)

Comment: @Neil Is there a good reason not to allow it? For example, is it off-topic according to the A51 example questions?

Comment: Aside from potential liability issues (addressed about), I can't think of any reason. The community isn't really weighing in on this, which is another problem entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia has a [medical disclaimer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Medical_disclaimer) that gets linked to from every page.

Maybe these could be adopted, and shown a bit more prominently e.g. if the question has a specific tag (`medical`, `legal`....)?

Answer (score 5):

In general, mosts answers have side-effects; anyone who tried to come back against a StackOverflow answer with "your coding snippet failed in my production system and we've lost orders worth $LOTS_OF_CURRENCY_UNITS" would be laughed at.

Medical liability is a particularly obvious edge case, but the general defence of "you should have consulted a professional" seems sound.