# Will a Q&A site about medical issues be provided?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I think a Q&A site about medical topics would be interesting. Is there any plan to make such a site available?

Comment: Related: [Is there any health-related site like Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33862/is-there-any-health-related-site-like-stack-overflow), [Health side effects due to cycling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161806/health-side-effects-due-to-cycling) and [Question asking for medical advice — is this a liability problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64559/question-asking-for-medical-advice-is-this-a-liability-problem)

Comment: +1 from me, wish there were one...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is [MedicalSciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) (formerly health.SE). It has been in public beta after graduating from [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) on 2015-04-23.