# Stack Exchange for health care

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Do we have meta site for health care like body exercise, yoga, health diet tips and other health related questions?

Comment: You want to browse the Area51 site to see proposed new StackExchange sites - http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=health

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a site proposal and belongs on Area51.

Comment: @Servy I dont know about area51, if proposal of new site is only objective of area51 then why stack exchange dont merge meta n area51?Since meta has everything about stack exchange with other site n issues in it

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Why *should* it merge the two?

Comment: @Servy cos meta has " site-commendation" tag.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Why is that a reason for meta to handle the site approval process?

Comment: @Servy  fine with that, but how my question is off topic n "site recommendation" tag On topic? I think meta has process by which que get transfer to other site, if you thinks so then migrate this question to area51 n remove mention tag.

Comment: You should use [Site recommendation] if you're not sure on which (existing) site to ask questions about a particular topic. Your question is not a good fit for a site recommendation, since it's mentioning a broad variety of topics and you didn't research any candidate sites. Area51 is for suggesting new sites and refining their definition.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71307/will-a-qa-site-about-medical-issues-be-provided

Comment: @nicael Sure why not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably searching for [Physical Fitness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com). Also, there is [Health](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) *proposal* on Area 51.