# Health side effects due to cycling

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Can I ask questions regarding health side effects due to cycling in [bicycles.stackexchange.com](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/)?
For example about the cramps, saddle sores, etc.
Can I also ask about the diet before and after a cycling session?

Comment: Which site are you referring to?

Comment: @Asad edited the question. Thanks for notifying

Comment: Why not ask this on the Meta of Bicycle? They will be able to help you way better.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I didn't know that there is a meta for separate stackexchanges. Can you please guide me to the meta for bicycles?

Comment: Are you kidding me?! You posted [a question on the Bicycle-Meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/770/can-i-ask-which-bicycle-i-can-buy) before...

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Oh thank you very much. Here after I will ask questions in specific meta. Now I know. Thank you all for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each site has its own Meta, which is where you should ask questions specific to that site.

After reviewing their [FAQ page](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1), if you are still unclear about whether a question would be on topic, bring this up on the [Bicycles Meta](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/). Users of Bicycles are much better equipped to answer questions about scope than the average user on this site.

Answer (score 2):

For questions regarding suitability of a topic ask on [the appropriate Meta](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com), you might want to explore or post to the [on-off-topic tag on meta.bicycles](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic). From their [FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If you're not quite sure if your question is on topic, consider looking at [meta questions tagged [on-off-topic]](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-off-topic) where the community has discussed what questions are appropriate for this site.

If that site does not fit the bill, you could also try [Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/). Do check out their [faq](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) beforehand.